# Mail delivery is not working on GitLab (installed from source)

Tags: email, gitlab

I just installed GitLab-8.14.4 from source. So everything seems to work fine except for the email when I create a new user (email notifications shouldn't either) email wasn't sent by GitLab.

My configuration is the following :

```
$ cat /home/git/gitlab/config/environments/production.rb  | grep -v '#'
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_files = false

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.compress = true

  config.log_level = :info

  %w{render_template render_partial render_collection}.each do |event|
  end

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {  
    :address              => "smtp.zoho.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'zoho.com',
    :user_name            => 'foo.bar@zoho.com',
    :password             => 'password',
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  config.eager_load = true

  config.allow_concurrency = false
end


$ cat /home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb | grep -v '#'

if Rails.env.production?
  Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.zoho.com",
    port: 587,
    user_name: "foo.bar@zoho.com",
    password: "password",
    domain: "zoho.com",
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    ca_path: "/etc/ssl/certs",
    ca_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
  }  
end
```

Then I monitored the log and I created a new user. Below the errors :

```
$ tail -f log/sidekiq.log

2016-12-12T16:08:13.515Z 5812 TID-nmp3w WARN: {"class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","queue":"mailers","args":[{"job_class":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","job_id":"610766e8-27ce-47ce-922f-54020a5460b7","queue_name":"mailers","arguments":["Notify","new_user_email","deliver_now",19,"y_oyURWrFzxhzY5eAx6m"],"locale":"en"}],"retry":3,"jid":"654a303c9440e2c91805591d","created_at":1481558893.355989,"enqueued_at":1481558893.3566873,"error_message":"Couldn't find User with 'id'=19","error_class":"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound","failed_at":1481558893.5128403,"retry_count":0}
2016-12-12T16:08:13.515Z 5812 TID-nmp3w WARN: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=19
2016-12-12T16:08:13.516Z 5812 TID-nmp3w WARN: /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:324:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:444:in `find_one'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:423:in `find_with_ids'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:71:in `find'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:131:in `find'
/home/git/gitlab/app/mailers/emails/profile.rb:4:in `new_user_email'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.7.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:596:in `block in process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:593:in `process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:584:in `initialize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `new'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `__getobj__'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:34:in `message'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_mailer/delivery_job.rb:10:in `perform'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:32:in `block in perform_now'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:257:in `with_locale'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/translation.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_perform_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:31:in `perform_now'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:21:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.7.1/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/sidekiq_adapter.rb:42:in `perform'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:155:in `execute_job'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:136:in `block (3 levels) in process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/request_store_middleware.rb:6:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:32:in `with_context'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:171:in `stats'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:130:in `block in process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq.rb:35:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq.rb:35:in `block in <module:Sidekiq>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:122:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:122:in `process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:81:in `process_one'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:69:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:17:in `watchdog'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Below some information about the installed environment :

```
$ bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:     
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  yes
RVM Version:    1.27.0
Ruby Version:   2.3.1p112
Gem Version:    2.5.1
Bundler Version:1.13.6
Rake Version:   10.5.0
Sidekiq Version:4.2.1

GitLab information
Version:    8.14.4
Revision:   3ea6c8d
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: postgresql
URL:        https://my.web.site
HTTP Clone URL: https://my.web.site/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@my.web.site:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    4.0.3
Repository storage paths:
- default:  /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

Do you have an idea of whats going on ? Please let me know if you need further details.

Comment: You have to show context, code where you queue worker so we can say something more

Comment: well actually I'm testing so I have no code to show and my problem is mail delivery in gitlab. So, I don't know what you want to see but feel free to ask that's why I'm here.

Comment: You have an error while sending email `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=19` this is the cause of not delivering email